# preg_match_all for links within a web site

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Would someone please show me how to use preg_match_all to capture a list  links where the destination web page is on the same web site?  All the links I am trying to capture in the search results are like this:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
<a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
```

Examples of links I do not want included in the results:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Visit Us On Facebook</a>
<a href="https://www.paypal.com">Pay Now</a>
```

I have spent an hour searching the web and have only found examples that show all the links within a web page, not exclusive to the same web site.

Thank you.

Comment: Just the links. The answer below is the help I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match all the anchor tags  in which the content of it's href attribute starts with  `/` symbol.

```
<a href="(\/[^"]*)">[^<>]*<\/a>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yI9tL6/1)

**Code:**

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOT
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
<a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Visit Us On Facebook</a>
<a href="https://www.paypal.com">Pay Now</a>
EOT;
echo preg_match_all('~<a href="(\/[^"]*)">[^<>]*<\/a>~', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
print_r($matches[1]);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
3Array
(
    [0] => <a href="/">Home</a>
    [1] => <a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
    [2] => <a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
)
Array
(
    [0] => /
    [1] => /about-us
    [2] => /contact-us
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using  [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)  ...

```
$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML('
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
    <a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com">Visit Us On Facebook</a>
    <a href="https://www.paypal.com">Pay Now</a>
');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//a[substring(@href, 1, 1) = "/"]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   $links[] = $node->getAttribute('href');
}
print_r($links);
```

<kbd>[**Code Demo**](https://eval.in/203914)</kbd>

You can as well use the `preg_match()` function with DOM.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$xpath->registerNamespace('php', 'http://php.net/xpath');
$xpath->registerPHPFunctions('preg_match');

$nodes = $xpath->evaluate("//a[php:functionString('preg_match', '~^/~', @href)=1]");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   $links[] = $node->getAttribute('href');
}
print_r($links);
```

<kbd>[**Code Demo**](https://eval.in/203916)</kbd>